# div class last div going under html css

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent the last div (class) from going under? I put `margin-right` on `.artist_wrap`. I thought when I put `overflow: hidden` it'll stay inside `#music_videos_wrap` but it disappears. Thanks to anyone who'll help me.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="music_videos_wrap">
    <div class="artist_wrap"></div>
    <div class="artist_wrap"></div>
    <div class="artist_wrap"></div>
    <div class="artist_wrap"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#music_videos_wrap{
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 23px;
    width:944px;
    height: 257px;
    background-color: red;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
.artist_wrap{
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    height:257px;
    background-color: green;
    margin:0 62px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: [Could you point out what's wrong in this jsFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/hBF2x/). I currently don't see any 'going under' effect occurring.

Comment: its supposed to be 4 .artist_wrap sorry

Comment: is it possible to "unmargin-right" the last .artist_wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you measurements are somewhat wrong, you need the wrapper to be 946px wide to fit the elements you want, alternatively change the width of the .artist_wrap. After fixing that, you could set margin-left:62px to .artist-wrapp instead of the right-margin. That way you could use margin-left:0 on first-child (which is more cross browser than last-child):

```
.artist_wrap:first-child { margin-left:0; }
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rkp3Z/

Comment: YAYYY thank youuuuu that :first-child isssss awesomee thank you very much i love you man! cool pseudo stuff

Answer (score 1):

your .artist_wrap width is too big

you should use firebug and adjust it see what is the max value that can fit in the parent's width

[here you go with 150px as width](http://jsfiddle.net/hBF2x/3/)

or compute it from the parents width subtracting the margin, borders and padding

```
944px parents width / 4 divs = 236 width per artist child
```

if you put right margin to each .artist_wrap you need to subtract this margin from the width to make it fit in the parent's 944 px width

which means 236 - 62 = 174px as width for artist_wrap

[you can also apply margin:0 31px for artist_wrap to have a symmetric layout](http://jsfiddle.net/hBF2x/4/)

Comment: i need those 4 .artist_wrap to fit inside it should fit because im slicing it from psd, i just want the last .artist_wrap to be "unmargin-right" so that it wont go under...